# What I need in order to share my SVN repository over the internet?

Tags: svn, repository, project, collaboration

I am using TortoiseSVN, I created a new repository, added users to the `passwd` file and committed a couple files to it locally.  I checked out locally and it seems to work.

Now I want to share that repository location with a friend over the Internet so that we can collaborate when my computer's on. What steps do I need to take? What IP or URL do I need to give him/her?

Comment: For this sort of use-case, I think you might be better served by a DVCS like Mercurial or Git. SVN isn't really designed for that sort of thing, it's mostly designed for an always-on server that multiple developers connect to. Mercurial and Git are both designed for collaborating with multiple independent developers without necessarily having a centralized always-on server. Mercurial even has a TortoiseHg client very similar to TortoiseSVN.

Comment: To expand further, SVN working copies are associated with a specific URL. Unless you have an unchanging name to use to access your repository, your friend will be forced to `svn relocate` every time your IP address changes (which probably happens quite regularly if your ISP acts like every ISP I've ever encountered, probably every time you reboot your computer, or even more frequently). Distributed Version Control Systems (DVCS) are NOT associated with a specific unchanging server address, so this problem, along with others, would go away.

Comment: If you want to use Subversion you should look into a repository hosting solution.  There are some free or low cost options available.  I've used Assembla but there are others I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Collabnet Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion). From that page:

> Free fully-automated installer/updater for software stacks of Subversion, Apache, and ViewVC frontend by a powerful web console for administration and server health check monitoring.

I've used it with success for a few years now. Just be aware, you might have some problems using the latest version (4.0.1) with older repositories, so if you can, recreate your repo with SVNEdge.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Subversion server that you can create on your end, doing the configuration and the installation, or you can also use a Subversion repository as a Service, which means that you can just use the Subversion repository on a hosting solution without doing anything, just enabling the service.

Subversion repositories are really cheap and you can also find some providers which could provide you some storage for free, you just need to look for it on Internet. As an example, you can use 2 GB for free on this [provider](http://www.cloudbees.com/platform/pricing/devcloud.cb).or

You should compare both options, and just choose the best option for your case.